# Search pattern using perl

Tags: perl, search, design-patterns

Newbie on Perl .

Need assistance in finding the search pattern on FTP server

Below example

```
# more file1
1 
2
3
```

Directory

```
# ls
1
2
3
4
```

How to search patter which are in the file and match the files in the directory using perl.
and display as below

```
1
2 
3
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

```
my $dir = "/path/to/some/dir";
my $filename = "some_filename";
my @files_to_find = ();

open my $file, '<', $filename or die $!;
while( my $line = <$file> ) {
    chomp $line;
    push @files_to_find, $line;
}
close $file;

for my $f (@files_to_find) {
    print "$f\n" if -e "$dir/$f";
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly what i wanted . thank you so much Kjprice . You are awsome perl programmer.

Comment: kjprice . This works perfectly fine on the local server . Can we use the same script to get the details from FTP.

Comment: I have a small code that works fine ...but i want to club this code to get the result

Comment: @AjayramGopu You'll have to write a sub that recursively searches directories on the ftp server

Comment: !/usr/bin/perl -w
use Net::FTP;
$ftp = Net::FTP->new("hostname");
$ftp->login('username', 'password');
$ftp->cwd("directory");
$ftp->binary;

my @filenames=$ftp->ls();
foreach (@filenames)
{
#  print "$_\n" ;
$ftp->quit();

I get the list of files on the server but i can i use your code to get the list of matched names .